# Как при помощи регулярных выражений получить часть текста

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть входная строка:

```
String input = "<td nowrap> <strong>2777461-1</strong><br><br> <small class=\"hidden-xs\"><b>Стол:</b> 1</small> < /td>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+?<strong>(.*)</strong>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

необходимо создать из этой строки 3 переменные

```
code = 2777461-1

furniture = Стол

count = 1
```

ошибок нет, но и даже code не удалось получить результат:

```
<strong>2777461-1</strong>
```

Может я ошибаюсь и регулярными выражениями такое не решается?

Comment: Регулярные выражения были придуманы чтобы можно было использовать в команде grep.

Comment: Для парсинга HTML используйте JSoup. Лучший вариант в данном случае.

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko При помощи JSoup я парсил. и вытащил входную строку и дальше как мне кажется JSoup мне уже не поможет, теперь надо из полученной строки выводить данные.

Comment: Какую строку вы получаете на выходе и какие данные не получается вытащить с помощью jsoup?

Comment: @p_redator все можно решить при помощи Jsoup. И по тегу вытащить данные и по номеру тега, просто доки почитать надо

Comment: @ Igor Konyaev при помощи jsoup я парсил по тегу <tr> ... набор данных  ... <\tr> по методу Elements div = doc.select("tr"); for (Integer i=1; i<div.size(); i++) { System.out.println(div.get(i).html()); } и получил набор из 7 строк одна из них входная указанная в самом начале, может я чего недопонимаю и можно из полученной строки при помощи jsoup еще раз парсить ?

Comment: @p_redator, вы можете до бесконечности идти по дереву вниз. Получив элементы по тэгу <tr>, перебирайте их в цикле и вызывайте необходимые методы на каждом элементе отдельно. Примерно так: for (Element e : div) { element.getElementsByAttribute("p")...и тд }. Никто вас не ограничивает в глубине обхода дерева, используте те же методы для этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый обычный вариант - использовать парсер, к примеру, jsoup. В вашем случае способ получить данные из документа будет выглядеть так:

```
String input = "<td nowrap> " +
                        "<strong id = \"strong\">2777461-1</strong>" +
                        "<br><br> " +
                        "<small class = \"hidden-xs\">" +
                            "<b id = \"furniture\">Стол:</b> " +
                            "<p id = \"count\"'>1</p>" +
                        "</small> " +
                    "</td>";
Document html = Jsoup.parse(input);

String strong = html.body().getElementById("strong").text();
String furniture = html.body().getElementById("furniture").text();
String count = html.body().getElementById("count").text();
```

Изучайте библиотеку, у нее есть масса способов парсинга html-документов.

Ремарка: для доступа к данным проще использовать id, который вы назначаете на нужный тэг. К примеру, если в документе будет 2 тэга , то по id вытащить строку будет оптимальнее (я подправил ваш исходный html, обратите на это внимание).

Comment: @ Igor Konyaev я не могу менять html страницу чтоб мне было удобно парсить.

Comment: Тогда используйте getElementsByTag(String tag). Потом можно смотреть все элементы, которые были получены из тэга. В случае с count используйте split(“ “), чтобы вернуть массив строк (вторым элементом будет «1»)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь всех откликнувшихся как указал Igor Konyaev на основе входной строки построил Document и через  Elements number = stringHtml.select("strong"); получил искомый code.